# openstack after passthrough RTX 3090 GPU - lspci says !!! Unknown header type 7f

Tags: linux, openstack-nova, passthrough, gpu, lspci

First thanks if you read this all, cause its like a long story.

We have cloud infrastructure on **Ubuntu 20.04** with **Linux 5.4.0-155-generic x86_64** kernel and **OpenStack** as virtualization system with **QEMU/KVM**. We have 4x `NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] [10de:2204] (rev a1)` card on our compute node. It works fine with pass-through and everything but after a while (about 1.5 years) suddenly one of RTX-3090s doesn't let us to create VM and nova shows `!!! Unknown header type 7f` on PCI device so I run `lspci -vnn | grep 2204 -A 4`
on Ubuntu host and unfortunately it says as follow:

```
25:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] [10de:2204] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:403b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 795, NUMA node 0
    Memory at c3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 2d060000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
--
61:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] [10de:2204] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:403b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 793, NUMA node 0
    Memory at cb000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 1d000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
--
c1:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] [10de:2204] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

--
c2:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] [10de:2204] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:403b]
    Physical Slot: 8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 792, NUMA node 1
    Memory at b9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
```

as you can see c1:00.0 pci address has RTX 3090 but It's not loaded correct pci device installed on the motherboard.

**OK now my problem is:** As far as I said other RTX3090s are using by other VM which has AI preprocessing on them so I **cannot** restart the compute node and want to solve the problem live so I can turn back the c1:00.0 RTX3090.

As I can see under `/sys/bus/pci/devices/PCI_PORT_ID/` there are some files `reset , remove , rescan` and people suggested to echo 1 on the reset or rescan file but it return me Permissions deny, and after I add `chmod +rw` tho aforesaid file(s) it says `I/O Error` and nothing happens :( .

The other solution I have found is to use `setpci -s PCI_PORT_ID BRIDGE_CONTROL=0052` and then `setpci -s PCI_PORT_ID BRIDGE_CONTROL=0012` to restart the pci device with setpci command and unfortunately its not working neither :(.

Isn't there any way I can restart my pci device to fix it? shall I have to loose hope and restart the all compute node?.

Thanks in advanced.